# How do I override incorrect types from a package that ships its own .d.ts?

Tags: typescript, checkjs

I am using chalk with a JavaScript project that I'm checking with TypeScript's `checkJs` flag.

The JavaScript code imports it like so:

```
const chalk = require('chalk')
```

Unfortunately, chalk ships its own types, and its types are wrong. It should use the syntax `export = chalk` (which is TypeScript's syntax for CommonJS) but instead does `export default chalk`.

Somebody [submitted a PR to fix it](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/pull/256), but the project hasn't merged any PRs in a while.

How can I work around the bad export from the chalk typings?

Answer (score 3):

You can override the package's types by providing a [path mapping](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping):

1. Create a file named `chalk-override.d.ts` in your project root. Copy the chalk types in there and fix them.
2. Add the following to your `tsconfig.json` (create one with `tsc --init --checkJs` if you haven't already):

   ```
   {
       // ... other settings ...

       "baseUrl": "./",
       "paths": {
           "chalk": ["chalk-override"]
       }
   }
   ```