# Importing typescript 4 package in typescript 3.8.3

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm working in a project that uses typescript 3.8.3 and I'm trying to import a newer package (specifically [win32-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32-api)).

I didn't think this should be a problem since the package is compiled to JavaScript, worst case, I don't have type information on the imported package.

After getting compilation errors for the `.d.ts` files of the imported package I added [`skipLibCheck`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck) to `tsconfig.json`, this makes no difference (did I misunderstand what this flag should do?).

My question is: Is there a way to tell TS to just use the JS parts of the other package?

Incidentally, I'm using [dynamic import](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) so that we can handle non-Window OSes. Is this relevant?

---

Please avoid answers on the form of "Just upgrade to a newer typescript", this is planned but I want a stop-gap solution.

---

#### Minimal code:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "skiplib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": { "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "win32-api": "^20.1.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "ES2017",
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import("win32-api").then(module => {
    console.log(`Loaded ${module}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible solution

### Solution limitations

Let's consider the worst case:

> I didn't think this should be a problem since the package is compiled to JavaScript, worst case, I don't have type information on the imported package.

Let's consider the question:

> My question is: Is there a way to tell TS to just use the JS parts of the other package?

As a limitation of the solution: yes, there is a way, but it does not include the type checking of such «JavaScript parts».

### Solution

The solution is to use the [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) to override the `win32-api` module with the shorthand module.

> All imports from a shorthand module will have the `any` type.
>
> — [TypeScript: Documentation - Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules).

### Draft example: Changes

#### `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "ES2017",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "win32-api": ["declarations/win32-api"]
        }
    }
}
```

#### `declarations/win32-api/index.d.ts` file

```js
declare module "win32-api";
```

#### Checks

##### TypeScript compiler: Output

```
$ npx tsc
$ cat index.js
Promise.resolve().then(() => require("win32-api")).then(module => {
    console.log(`Loaded ${module}`);
});
```

##### TypeScript compiler: List of files contains overridden module

```
$ npx tsc --listFilesOnly | grep -F 'declarations/win32-api'
<PROJECT_DIRECTORY_PATH>/declarations/win32-api/index.d.ts
```

### Additional references

- Question. [typescript - Exclude/overwrite npm-provided typings - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627631/exclude-overwrite-npm-provided-typings).
- Question. [typescript - How do I override incorrect types from a package that ships its own .d.ts? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884527/how-do-i-override-incorrect-types-from-a-package-that-ships-its-own-d-ts).
- GitHub issue. [Can't disable type definitions for one special library · Issue #17042 · microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17042).
- GitHub issue. [Suggestion: add excludeTypeRoots to tsconfig · Issue #18588 · microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18588).

  - [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18588#issuecomment-629249692).